# mock functions from current file

Tags: node.js, sinon

I have code which defines 3 functions. 2 standalone functions and 1 that uses the two others.

```
const info = (msg) => {
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    console.info(chalk.hex('#00f2ff')(msg));
};

const failure = (msg) => {
    /* istanbul ignore next */
    console.error(chalk.hex('#F9060B')(msg));
};

/**
 * create configuration with configuration file's values if present
 * make related prompts to be skipped
 *
 * @resolves configuration object
 */
const init = () => fse.readJson(cst.configFile)
    .then((config) => {...})
    .catch((error) => {
        if (error.errno === -2) {
            info(cst.messages.noConfig);
        } else {
            failure(error);
        }
        return {}; // if an error occurs, loads nothing.
    });
```

I'm testing the function init and not the two others. I thus want to stub info and failure. While this seems a very basic use case, I didn't find any documentation on it in sinon documentation.

The problem seems to be that the function doesn't come from a 'require' nor is it an object I provide to the tested function.

How would you do it ? Or am I trying to do something wrong ?

Here is what I would expect to work :

```
it('informs when there is no configuration file and resolves empty object', function () {
    fseMock.expects('readJson').rejects({ errno: -2 });

    const infoStub = sandbox.stub(prompt, 'info');

    return prompt.init().then((config) => {
        assert.equal(infoStub.firstCall.args[0], cst.messages.noConfig);
        assert.deepEqual(config, {});
    });
});
```

Comment: Is `init` exported? How does your test have access to `init` and not `info`/`failure` if they are all in the same file?

Comment: My test has access to all three of them. I wouldn't be able to mock init if I was trying to. But obviously I won't mock the function I'm testing.

Comment: I understand that, but your test implies that the functions are properties on the `prompt` object, but your code containing the 3 functions doesn't reflect that. To rephrase my previous question: How did `init` find its way onto the `prompt` object?

Comment: `module.exports = {info, failure, init};` on prompt.js side and `const prompt = require('path-to-prompt.js');` on the test side.